# cmd doesn't show all results

Tags: c#, cmd, command-prompt

i'm wondering i started programming 6 monthes ago but never noticed that cmd can't show all results and it seems that there is limit. for example try this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

you may not noticed at first but if you run this it only covers from 701 to 999 and you can't find 0 to 700, it seems that cmd only can show 299 lines and the previous result will be hide if you have more than that line. Am i correct? What is the problem? whats the reason for that?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the command prompt has properties:

[image]

And under those properties you can adjust the default buffer higher or lower as needed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set the buffer to the size of the loop to see all the entries.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setbuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setbuffersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

e.g.

```
Console.SetBufferSize(80, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the `Console.BufferHeight` property (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.bufferheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

```
Console.BufferHeight = 1200; //set the bufferheight to 1200 lines
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```